# Android - post Runnable to UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading

If I am not mistaken, you can find out if the current thread is the UI thread by doing:

```
if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper())
    /* we are in the UI thread */
```

How can I post a task to the UI thread/queue?

```
if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper())
    X.execute(new Runnable() { ... });
```

Here, X is the queue/handler of the UI Thread. What is X, and can get I get it statically?

I would like to send this task without being forced to have a reference to my activity or anything else. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `X` and what do you want to run into `Runnable`?

Comment: X refers to my question. I want to ask what X is. X is the queue/handler corresponding to the UI thread. The Runnable contains some code which should run in the UI thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably recommend looking at context.runOnUiThread(Runnable r);
No need to check the looper - the runOnUiThread(...) function will do that for you.